# Request for simple parameter in Postman is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, postman

I am new to Postman. The Get queries work fine but I can't send Post. 
I work with Net .Core.
In my controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(Order model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I am getting error 400 if I am trying to add Content-Type manually or 415 if I leave it as is and just set JSON. 
[image: Postman screenshot]

Comment: For some reason, it is working for me only if I pass the parameter through the ray option

Answer (score 1):

That's because your payload is sent as `querystring` instead of `appliation/json`.

1. The `Params` becomes `querystring` in the URL
2. I didn't see there's a green dot besides the `Body`. It's likely that you **didn't specify a body**. In other words, the `Body` is empty.

[image: Your Screenshot]

It seems that you want to send a payload of `application/JSON` to server. If that's the case, make sure:

1. Add a header of `Content-Type: application/json` in `Headers`
2. Add a well-formatted JSON payload in the `Body` Tab：

   [image]

---

By the way,

1. A controller annotated with **`[ApiController]`** expects a payload of **`application/json`** by default, which means the clients need send a well-formatted JSON with header of `application/json`.
2. However, if you're using **a plain controller** instead of `[ApiController]`, the body payload by default should be **a form**. In most cases they'll be **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**.

PostMan allows us to sends payload of different Content-Types. Please do check the related radio button when there's a need.